# pytorch math with exponents less than 1 return nan 's

Tags: python, function, pytorch, documentation

torch.pow() returns nan when it's given the exponent argument between ranges -1 and 1

```
a = torch.randn(1,3)
a

>> tensor([[-1.7871, -0.5375, -0.1164]])

torch.pow(a, 2)      #or a**2

>> tensor([[3.1938, 0.2889, 0.0136]])

torch.pow(a,0.5)     #or a**0.5

>> tensor([[nan, nan, nan]])
```

expect result:

```
tensor([[-1.3368, -0.7331, -0.3412]])
```

Edit: turns out that ** works the same way as well. `a**2` does the same thing with the tensor as `torch.pow(a,2)`.  `a**0.5` returns nan's like torch.pow does.

Comment: Why is it the expected result?

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that square root of a negative number is a non-real complex number.

If you want to keep the sign and take the square root of its absolute value, the following code does the trick

```
torch.sign(a) * torch.pow(torch.abs(a), 0.5)
```